# Better Way to Show and Hide Items in Project

Tags: vb.net

I have this code snippet below that I am looking for a way to make smaller if possible.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Private Sub ShowAlternateRows(Show As Boolean)
    If Show = True Then
        splitter.Visible = True
        lblAlternateActualPercent.Visible = True
        lblAltEstimated.Visible = True
        lblStaticAltEstimated.Visible = True

        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Type").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Start").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate End").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Hours").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Burn").Visible = True

        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Estimated").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("End Estimated").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Actual").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("End Actual").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Estimated Hours").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Actual Hours").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Burn Estimated").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Object Count").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Request Count").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Resource Count").Visible = False

        lblStaticActual.Visible = False
        lblActual.Visible = False
        lblActualPercent.Visible = False
        lblStaticEstimated.Visible = False
        lblEstimated.Visible = False
        lblStaticFiltered.Visible = False
        lblFiltered.Visible = False
        lblFilteredPercent.Visible = False

    Else
        splitter.Visible = False
        lblAlternateActualPercent.Visible = False
        lblAltEstimated.Visible = False
        lblStaticAltEstimated.Visible = False

        lblStaticActual.Visible = True
        lblActual.Visible = True
        lblActualPercent.Visible = True
        lblStaticEstimated.Visible = True
        lblEstimated.Visible = True
        lblStaticFiltered.Visible = True
        lblFiltered.Visible = True
        lblFilteredPercent.Visible = True

        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Estimated").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("End Estimated").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Actual").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("End Actual").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Estimated Hours").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Actual Hours").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Burn Estimated").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Object Count").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Request Count").Visible = True
        Grid.Cols.Item("Resource Count").Visible = True

        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Type").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Start").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate End").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Hours").Visible = False
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Burn").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `OPTION STRICT OFF` (since I don't know the type of `Grid.Cols.Item`):

```
Private Sub ShowAlternateRows(show As Boolean)
    Dim grpShow = 
    {
        splitter, lblAlternateActualPercent, 
        lblAltEstimated, lblStaticAltEstimated,  
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Type"), Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Start"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate End"),  Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Hours"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Alternate Burn")
    }
    Dim grpHide = 
    {
        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Estimated"), Grid.Cols.Item("End Estimated"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Start Actual"),    Grid.Cols.Item("End Actual"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Estimated Hours"), Grid.Cols.Item("Actual Hours"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Burn Estimated"),  Grid.Cols.Item("Object Count"),
        Grid.Cols.Item("Request Count"),   Grid.Cols.Item("Resource Count"),
        lblStaticActual,  lblActual,
        lblActualPercent, lblStaticEstimated,
        lblEstimated, lblStaticFiltered,
        lblFiltered,  lblFilteredPercent
    }
    For Each ctrl in grpShow
        ctrl.Visible = show
    Next
    For Each ctrl in grpHide
        ctrl.Visible = Not show
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This does cut things down 1/2 at least, ty.

Comment: @AdamShip Yeah; also, the code duplication is removed. You could save 4 more lines by replacing the `For Each` loops by using lists and using the `ForEach()` extension method, but I would not recommend doing so because of the loss of readability.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you can put the labels in 1 or more panels, you can just show/hide the panels. This means instead of:

```
splitter.Visible = Show
lblAlternateActualPercent.Visible = Show
lblAltEstimated.Visible = Show
lblStaticAltEstimated.Visible = Show

lblStaticActual.Visible = Not Show
lblActual.Visible = Not Show
lblActualPercent.Visible = Not Show
lblStaticEstimated.Visible = Not Show
lblEstimated.Visible = Not Show
lblStaticFiltered.Visible = Not Show
lblFiltered.Visible = Not Show
lblFilteredPercent.Visible = Not Show
```

You could do something like:

```
Panel1.Visible = Show
Panel2.Visible. Not Show
```

Also, noticed how I used `Show` or `Not Show` instead if an If/Else statement with all the code twice.

Last, Itererate through the columns, assuming that you want to do something with each column. (I am assuming Grid.Cols returns a DataGridColumnCollection. You might need to change for your specific type)

```
For each col as DataGridColumn in Grid.Cols
  If col.Name.tolower.StartsWith("alternate ") then
    col.visible = Show
  Else
    col.Visible = Not Show
  End If
Next
```